# C# 'out' keyword in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, comparative-review

Since I met the [`out` keyword in C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier), I'm trying to find an equivalent in JS.

So, please take a look at the code and leave your opinions or suggestions about this.

## C# example:

```cs
string numberAsString = "1640";

if (Int32.TryParse(numberAsString, out int number)) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Converted '{numberAsString}' to {number}");
}
```

## JS Example #1: Direct approach:

```js
const numberAsString = '1640';
const number = tryParse(numberAsString);

if (typeof number === 'number') {
    console.log(`Converted '${numberAsString}' to ${number}`);
}
```

To break it down - we are not only getting one value instead of 2 (c# returns boolean and creates int). But we also have to double-check the output. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric

And we got one extra line of code, which is very important for me.

## JS Example #2: KVP response approach:

```js
const numberAsString = '1640';
const { isNumber, number } = tryParse(numberAsString);

if (isNumber) {
    console.log(`Converted '${numberAsString}' to ${number}`);
}
```

This is much better IMHO, at the cost of the small complexity of working with objects.

Aaand... It's still one line more!

## JS Example #3: Pass by refference approach:

```js
const numberAsString = '1640';
const refNumber = { value: 0 };

if (tryParse(numberAsString, refNumber)) {
    console.log(`Converted '${numberAsString}' to ${refNumber.value}`);
}
```

It's much better and very close to C#. But you have to know a little about JS. And to know that everything in it is an Object and an Object is always passed by reference.

OMG! That line is driving me crazy!!

## JS Example #4: Exploit conditional expression:

It's time to play dirty!

```js
const numberAsString = '1640';

if (typeof (number = tryParse(numberAsString)) === 'number') {
    console.log(`Converted '${numberAsString}' to ${number}`);
}
```

Aahhh... finally THE line is gone. But at what cost?.. Double-checking of the result is back. And the worst part (as per the community's opinion) is variable assignment inside conditional's expression.

## JS Example #5: Exploit IIFE and Short circuits:

As we are already down and dirty, let's keep on.

```js
const numberAsString = '1640';

const number = tryParse(numberAsString) ?? (() => console.log('Fail'))();
```

Well, this version I like a lot. Because you can fall back elegantly with fewer lines. And it even removes one indentation level. The downside is that it involves a not popular pattern and is applicable only for `null` or `falsy` cases. 0 is `falsy`, thus I used here the `??` instead of `||`..

## JS Example #6: The mad professor approach:

### WARNING! The next lines may irreversible twist your mind.

Scroll and look at your own risk.

```js
const numberAsString = '1640';

for (var i, number = tryParse(numberAsString); !i && null !== number; i = 1) {
    console.log(`Converted '${numberAsString}' to ${number}`);
}
```

(Cough)... Well, it's working, try it in the console if you don't believe me.

So, what the heck is happening?

Firstly, `var` is an ancient keyword that has some primordial magic inside it and it is **jumping** outside scopes. So far I know about `for` and `try catch`, maybe there are more, but it's too ancient for me to know them all.

Secondly, `for` is the only space in JS that is allowing you to declare variables outside the plain scope. So, that space between `(` and first `;` - you can use as plain scope to declare something or to break something or someone...

Thirdly, space between `;` and `;` is considered something like an `if` expression. So combining with variables declared before, you can exploit the third part which will make your loop go only once if the second validation is passed.

The thing is that you are actually not breaking any rules of JS. The best part is that IDE understands it and when you `Ctrl + Click` on the variable used outside `for` - it will jump right where it's declared.

So... at the cost of your and the ones that will read your code, sanity... It's an interesting tradeoff.

---

So, please leave your answers with your opinions and suggestions of other approaches.

Comment: What do you mean by "double checking"? Why is #2 better than #1 - don't they both effectively have the same "check that `number` contains a number, then do stuff with that number" pattern? And if you're fine with declaring a variable in an `if` condition in the c# example, why is doing the same thing in #4 a problem? Also, why is having the code be one (1) line longer even a concern?

Comment: @SaraJ #1 and #2 are far NOT the same. #1 returns a number while you must be sure it's a number you do some checkings inside and the same checkings go into `if` #2 has the result of checking exposed therefore you are not reusing the result. That's the answer to the first question. For the rest questions, I need more space, so I will just write to read the explanations below code.

Comment: This is completely not the point of your question, but JavaScript comes with an `isNaN(x)` function, which is the compliment to `Number(x)`. If Number(x) returns a `NaN` (Not a Number) value, then isNaN(x) will return true. In a way, that kind of does what you want. The Number(x) function returns a parsed number, or `NaN` if it could not parse it.

Comment: Of course the point of this whole code exercise was not parsing strings as numbers, but replicating the C# `out` parameters. :P So my suggestion is moot.

Comment: @SaraJ When you see something like this you might want to tell the users in The 2nd Monitor.

Comment: This is completely off-topic for Code Review. It doesn't appear to be a request for a code review. Where is the working code from your project? What does the code do?

Comment: @pacmaninbw, what do you understand by "Code Review"? I think you got the wrong idea.

Comment: I suggest you read the entire [asking section](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking) starting with [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  The question is too hypothetical.

Comment: @pacmaninbw do you want me to remove the question? It is such an eye sore for you?

Comment: First I want you to understand why it is off-topic so that when you do ask another question it will be a better question and may become a Hot Network Question. That is why I suggested you read the help section. Care to join me in the [Code Review Chat}*https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)?

Answer (score 4):

None of these seem like a winner. I would do something like:

```javascript
function withParsed(string, success, error) {
    const number = parseInt(string, 10)
    if(!isNaN(number))
      return success(number)
    
    return error(string)
}

withParsed(
    '1234', 
    (number) => console.log(`This is a number: ${number}`), 
    (string) => console.log(`String ${string} is not a number`)
)
```

Error callback is optional and you can remove it, but it seems that in #5 you wanted to handle the fail also, so I included it.

Anyway, all this seems like a backwards approach to a simple try catch:

```javascript
function parseOrThrow(string) {
  const number = parseInt(string, 10)
  if(isNaN(number)) throw 'Not a valid number'
  return number
}

try{
  const number = parseOrThrow('123')
  console.log(number)
} catch(e) {
  console.log('Fail')
}
```

Which can be packaged into a function anyway to look like:

```javascript
function logIfNumber(string) {
  try {
    const number = parseOrThrow(string)
    console.log(number)
  } catch(e) {
  }
}

logIfNumber('123')
```

If you are bothered by the empty catch, you can have a helper:

```javascript
function tryTo(fn) {
  try {
    fn()
  } catch(e) {}
}

function logIfNumber(string) {
  tryTo(() => {
    const number = parseOrThrow(string)
    console.log(number)
  })
}
```

This C# pattern is a bit weird to me, because it is a glorified try-catch, but with if-else and it should be in a different method/function anyway.

Comment: The idea of passing in callbacks really is interesting. Thank you! But the whole idea of this article is to mimic C# 'out' keyword. That is you have a function that does two things at the same time: parse if success and return value to work with and second is the false case to just ignore.

Comment: @Eugene Why do you want to find this?

Comment: What do you mean why? The professional curiosity of course!

Comment: Fwiw the TryParse functions in C# are not exactly equivalent to regular Parse in a try...catch block. Rather Byte.Parse and Byte.TryParse for example are implemented as two separate functions each relying on parallel helper functions tryFoo / Foo so that the [try path](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/byte.cs,138) always tracks success while the [other path](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/byte.cs,116) always bubbles exceptions if that makes sense? Basically avoids having to catch all exceptions.

Comment: @Greedo The point still stands. The code in an if block would be better off, if it was in a separate method wrapped in a try-catch. Also, the 'other path' example you sent would be cleaner if it was int i = parseToInt32OrThrow(...); if(i < min || i > max) throw ...; return (byte)i;. Instead of that awkward try-catch dangling in the middle. The parseToInt32OrThrow method would then have just return Number.ParseInt32(...) in the try portion.

Comment: Oh yeah, your point on using try catch in this instance where `parseInt` is defined and `tryParseInt` isn't is definitely valid. I guess in the example I linked (the official c# source btw), they do that try catch because they want to change the exception text from `Int32` to `Byte`, so they catch and rethrow a new exception. Anyway, I think in your answer maybe it's worth pointing out `catch(e)` could/should rethrow unexpected errors, since you would probably expect even tryParse to error on a keyboard interrupt or something. C# never suppresses errors in its tryFoo so doesn't have to worry.

Comment: I know these are the official docs, and I think they do that because it is more efficient (one function call less). They could rethrow in the private method all the same and nothing would change, just the code will be easier for the eyes (life hacks - if you have a try catch, you can make it a separate method and nothing will change... and you can get rid of empty variable definitions before the try catch block - like that int i in the docs). What do you mean by never suppresses? It returns false instead of the actual error. It technically never suppresses it, but it doesn't throw it either :D

Answer (score 1):

I'll add another answer, because the previous one was focused on making code readable.

```
string numberAsString = "1640";

if (Int32.TryParse(numberAsString, out int number)) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Converted '{numberAsString}' to {number}");
}
```

This is ugly. And it is ugly because you are mutating some value inside another function. It was probably meant as some sort of syntactic sugar, but it just makes no sense.

## JS Example #1:

```javascript
const numberAsString = '1640';
const number = tryParse(numberAsString);

if (typeof number === 'number') {
    console.log(`Converted '${numberAsString}' to ${number}`);
}
```

This does not make sense, because you are parsing the number, but still have to check if the number is of number type outside the parsing function. What is the function good for then?

## JS Example #2:

```javascript
const numberAsString = '1640';
const { isNumber, number } = tryParse(numberAsString);

if (isNumber) {
    console.log(`Converted '${numberAsString}' to ${number}`);
}
```

This is indeed better, but still... What is the purpose of trying to parse something and returning if parsing was successful? The problem I'm having is that you are "Trying to parse", but I can say "And if you fail?" and your function goes "I'll tell you I couldn't" and to that I can go "You are useless", because this sounds like something we already know... a try-catch block.

## JS Example #3:

```javascript
const numberAsString = '1640';
const refNumber = { value: 0 };

if (tryParse(numberAsString, refNumber)) {
    console.log(`Converted '${numberAsString}' to ${refNumber.value}`);
}
```

This is the worst offender so far. Mutating objects inside a function is not a good approach, especially if it is an expected result. The following snippet is horrific:

```javascript
let result = {}
add(1, 2, result)
console.log(result.sum)
```

Even if result was not an object, but an int in something like C, it would make no sense to send a pointer as a result into a function to be mutated. If you are expecting a result you return it from a function.

## JS Example #4:

```javascript
const numberAsString = '1640';

if (typeof (number = tryParse(numberAsString)) === 'number') {
    console.log(`Converted '${numberAsString}' to ${number}`);
}
```

This is actually identical to #1.

## JS Example #5:

```javascript
const numberAsString = '1640';

const number = tryParse(numberAsString) ?? (() => console.log('Fail'))();
```

This is actually what I'm having problem with here. So tryParse returns null if string cannot be parsed. Why did you check for typeof number === 'number' before. It was a useless check. Also, the behavior is completely different in this example than all previous ones. This prints nothing if number is a number and prints Fail if number is not defined.

## JS Example #6:

```javascript
const numberAsString = '1640';

for (var i, number = tryParse(numberAsString); !i && null !== number; i = 1) {
    console.log(`Converted '${numberAsString}' to ${number}`);
}
```

Not even going to comment on this, because it falls victim to the same problem as #5

Why not:

```javascript
let number
if(!!(number = tryParse(numberAsString))) {
  ...
}
```

but then again, if number is used after this if statement, you will have to check if number is null again. Number is only meant to be used inside the if statement. This means that it is in isolated context. Like... idk... a function.

What you are trying to do is to reproduce a dirty code smell in the purest language written by god himself xD

But seriously, I would consider what you are trying to do a smell, because you can isolate the if statement into a separate function with try-catch and give it a name, which makes your code more readable and clearer.

Comment: Hmm, thank you for your detailed comments, it is useful. Though at some points you did not get the gist of examples, but still good to have. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This statement is concerning to me:
`To break it down - we are not only getting one value instead of 2 (c# returns boolean and creates int).`

TryParse does not *create* an integer. If you tried to compile the following code:

```cs
static void Main() {
    int.TryParse("123", out myval);
}
```

You will get the following error:

```cs
error CS0103: The name `myval` does not exist in the current context
```

Even if you tried to the following:

```cs
static void Main() {
    int.TryParse("123", out int myval);
}
```

`myval` still is created in the main function's context.

Whether you use `out` or `ref` the argument is passed by reference. See [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/ref-vs-out-keywords-in-C-Sharp) for more details.

Comment: Well, that's case #3 for you. Thanks!

Comment: You got it all wrong. `TryParse` does not create, but `out int number` does.

Comment: @Eugene. I respectfully disagree ;-) Have a look at the following: [TIO](https://tio.run/##fVHBasMwDL37K0RPCWy9rYeG7TLoaYPCDju7rlIMjjUsu6OMfHsqu12aZWM6mff0pKdnw/cdeRqGxNYf4O3EEbtGKeM0M2yI1JcCqY@0c9ZkoKoLcIFzPZNncrh8Dzbii/VYLVqiNRjBY0gmUgDLYLRzuF/UTRH2ajrW@gjd6ahdo4S4Lt8GOgTdiYHSylFHad0ROdjqwJi9ZKHI7oBSzOZANs/92RYq6YEneKhH8EbnEhU8gsfPy4HNnFwWc9JSLE7JgDEFD3In3oh@fKFj/H9ncn9PbLVI5yNzOJMsjmT38Kqt//UnY0Crn9F8h9@rYTgD), The referrence to foo is still created in `Main`.

Comment: @Eugene, this is exactly the same [TIO](https://tio.run/##fVHBTsMwDL3nK6ydWgl2gwMVXJB2AmkSB85Z5k6R0hjFydCE@u3FSUdbFYRP0Xt@9vOL4duOPA1DYutP8HbhiF2jlHGaGXZE6kuB1Ec6OGsyUNUFGOFcz@SZHG7fg434Yj1Wm5boAYzgMSQTKYBlMNo5PG7qpgh7tRxrfYTuctauUUJcl@8DnYLuxEBp5aijtB6IHOx1YMxeslBkN0ApZnMgm9f@bAuV9MAT3NUTONO5RAWP4PFzPLBZk9tiTlqKxSUZMKbgQe7EmeinFzrG/3cm9/fEVot0PTKHs8jiTPYIr9r6X39yjWLWT4ndj1nlnH5@olfD8A0)

Comment: So yes, I'm right. You have two cases: 1) `Foo foo` is created line above; 2) `out Foo foo` is created inline. What do you disagree with?

Comment: And besides that, where did you read that I wrote `TryParse` creates something? I specifically wrote `c#` which infers the whole code or that specific line to be more precise.

Comment: @Eugene, I'm not even sure anymore, Perhaps this is the closest you'll get in Javascript [TIO](https://tio.run/##Ncw9C8IwEMbxPZ/i6JRAFV82izi7FPfS4YiJREpS7i6CiJ89JoPr8/z5PfGFbCmssonp7koRet@Q2MEZfI5WQoqae0CjPgoAcNrN9Vpbco2i2QxtJieZIgQecdStMXABj0t1TiCU3aC@SgUP@u/rbn84dj1Q1abZmKbYFDktbrukh6aGlPID)

Comment: Thank you. That's case #3 for you  :D

Comment: @Eugene, yeah but it's on one line =). Anyway, I give up, thanks for hurting my head, lol.

Comment: Never give up! Coding is a world that never ceases to evolve! Well unless GitHub Copilot decides otherwise to remove the only weakness it has... the developers :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130444/discussion-between-johan-du-toit-and-eugene).